# How can I calculate percentile in java without using any other library

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap, percentile

I am trying to calculate `95th Percentile` from the data sets which I have populated in my below `ConcurrentHashMap`.

**I am interested in finding out how many calls came back in 95th percentile of time**

My Map will look like this and it will always be sorted in ascending order on the keys- In which

```
key - means number of milliseconds
value - means number of calls that took that much milliseconds
```

Below is my Map data-

```
Milliseconds    Number

0               1702
1               15036
2               14262
3               13190
4               9137
5               5635
6               3742
7               2628
8               1899
9               1298
10              963
11              727
12              503
13              415
14              311
15              235
16              204
17              140
18              109
19              83
20              72
```

For example, from the above data sets, it means

> 1702 calls came back in 0 milliseconds
>
> 15036 calls came back in 1 milliseconds

Now I can calculate the 95th percentile by plugging the above data sets in the `Excel sheet`. But I was thinking to calculate the percentile in Java code.

I know the algorithm will look something like this-

> Sum all values from the map, calculate 95% of the sum, iterate the map
>   keys in ascending order keeping a running total of values, and when
>   sum equals or exceeds the previously calculated 95% of the total sum,
>   the key should be the 95th percentile I guess.

Below is the map which will have above data sets.

```
Map<Long, Long> histogram = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long>
```

I am not sure whether I am algorithm is also correct or not. I am just trying to find out how many calls came back in 95th percentile of time.

Below is the code I have got so far basis on my above algorithm.

```
private static void logPercentileInfo() {

    double total = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Long, Long> entry : CassandraTimer.histogram.entrySet()) {
        long value = entry.getKey() * entry.getValue();
        total += value;
    }

    double sum = 0.95*total;

    double totalSum = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Long, Long> entry : CassandraTimer.histogram.entrySet()) {
        totalSum += entry.getValue();

        if(totalSum >= sum) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());//this is the 95th percentile I guess
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if I got everything correct in calculating the 95th percentile from my above data sets. If there is any improvement as well, please let me know.

**Updated Code:-**

Below is my updated code which solves the problem for ascending order of keys

```
/**
 * A simple method to log 95th percentile information
 */
private static void logPercentileInfo() {

    double total = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Long, Long> entry : CassandraTimer.histogram.entrySet()) {
        long value = entry.getKey() * entry.getValue();
        total += value;
    }

    double sum = 0.95*total;

    double totalSum = 0;

    SortedSet<Long> keys = new TreeSet<Long>(CassandraTimer.histogram.keySet());
    for (long key : keys) {

        totalSum += CassandraTimer.histogram.get(key);

        if(totalSum >= sum) {
           //this is the 95th percentile I guess
            System.out.println(key);
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone take a look and let me know whether I am calculating the percentile correctly or not?

Comment: Since you are using a hash map your keys aren't going to be stored in sorted order.  I.e., if you print out entry.getKey() in your loop you are going to see that the keys are not in order.  So that is your main problem.  A TeeMap or ConcurrentSkipListMap will keep its keys in order.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I forgot doing that. But keeping that in mind, my map has already the data in sorted order then the logic is right?

Comment: Are you sure?  Print your keys I'll bet you'll see that they are not in order.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that part. I was in the impression, I am storing it in sorted order. Let me make that correction and then I will update my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment on your question:

> Since you are using a hash map your keys aren't going to be stored in sorted order. I.e., if you print out entry.getKey() in your loop you are going to see that the keys are not in order. So that is your main problem. A TeeMap or ConcurrentSkipListMap will keep its keys in order

changing `Map<Long, Long> histogram = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long>`

to

`Map<Long, Long> histogram = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<Long, Long>()`

will give you a map that'll return your keys in sorted order.

Another issue in your code is when you calculate the total sum you do:

`total += entry.getKey() * entry.getValue(); // total += key*value`

and when you calculate the sum the second time around you are doing:

`totalSum += CassandraTimer.histogram.get(key); // totalSum += value`

I think you want to count up the total number of observations and then multiply that by 0.95.  That'll give you the number of observations below the 95th percentile.

`L = .95 * total_observations`

Then iterate over your map, summing up the number of observations.  Once the total number of observations exceeds `L` then the corresponding key is the value at the 95th percentile.

```
private static void logPercentileInfo() {
    double total = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Long, Long> entry : CassandraTimer.histogram.entrySet()) {
        long value = entry.getValue();
        total += value;
    }

    double sum = 0.95*total;
    double totalSum = 0;

    SortedSet<Long> keys = new TreeSet<Long>(CassandraTimer.histogram.keySet());
    for (long key : keys) {

        totalSum += CassandraTimer.histogram.get(key);

        if(totalSum >= sum) {
           System.out.println(key);
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt for the suggestion. I have updated my question with the latest code. Can you please take a look and let me know whether the way I am doing is right or not this time?

Comment: you are calculating the sum differently in the different loops.  I updated my answer.

Comment: I thought that is the right way to do that? Take a look at my algorithm for my question. In my question, I have key and value. Key is the number of milliseconds and value is the total number of calls for that milliseconds? `For example, 72 calls came back in 20 milliseconds`

Comment: I agree with Matt, to get the `total` in the first loop you merely want to add up all of the values in the map and not `(key * value)`.

Comment: @Matt Can you provide an example for me basis on my code. I guess this is getting confusing for me now. It will be of great help if you can provide me an example. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating a `ConcurrentHashMap` does not return the keys in order.  You will first need to create a sorted list of the keys and then iterate that when pulling out the values from the `histogram` in the latter loop.

Comment: Let me make that correction in my code and will update the code again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks Ed for the suggestion. I have updated my question with the latest code. Can you please take a look and let me know whether the way I am doing is right or not this time?